# Fastest way to diff datasets and update/insert lots of rows into large MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

### The schema

I have a MySQL database with one large table (5 million rows say). This table has several fields for actual data, an optional comment field, and fields to record when the row was first added and when the data is deleted. To simplify to one "data" column, it looks a bit like this:

```
+----+------+---------+---------+----------+
| id | data | comment | created | deleted  |
+----+------+---------+---------+----------+
| 1  | val1 | NULL    | 1       | 2        |
| 2  | val2 | nice    | 1       | NULL     |
| 3  | val3 | NULL    | 2       | NULL     |
| 4  | val4 | NULL    | 2       | 3        |
| 5  | val5 | NULL    | 3       | NULL     |
```

This schema allows us to look at any past version of the data thanks to the `created` and `deleted` fields e.g.

```
SET @version=1;
SELECT data, comment FROM MyTable
WHERE created <= @version AND 
      (deleted IS NULL OR deleted > @version);

+------+---------+
| data | comment |
+------+---------+
| val1 | NULL    |
| val2 | nice    |
```

The current version of the data can be fetched more simply:

```
SELECT data, comment FROM MyTable WHERE deleted IS NULL;

+------+---------+
| data | comment |
+------+---------+
| val2 | nice    |
| val3 | NULL    |
| val5 | NULL    |
```

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE `MyTable` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `deleted` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `data` (`data`,`comment`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

### Updating

Periodically a new set of data and comments arrives. This can be fairly large, half a million rows say. I need to update `MyTable` so that this new data set is stored in it. This means:

- **"Deleting" old rows.** Note the "scare quotes" - we don't actually delete rows from `MyTable`. We have to set the `deleted` field to the new version `N`. This has to be done for all rows in `MyTable` that are in the previous version `N-1`, but are not in the new set.
- **Inserting new rows.** All rows that are in the new set and are not in version `N-1` in `MyTable` must be added as new rows with the `created` field set to the new version `N`, and `deleted` as NULL.

Some rows in the new set may match existing rows in `MyTable` at version `N-1` in which case there is nothing to do.

### My current solution

Given that we have to "diff" two sets of data to work out the deletions, we can't just read over the new data and do insertions as appropriate. I can't think of a way to do the diff operation without dumping all the new data into a temporary table first. So my strategy goes like this:

```
-- temp table uses MyISAM for speed.
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempUpdate (
    `data` char(32) NOT NULL,
    `comment` char(32) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`data`),
    KEY (`data`, `comment`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

-- Bulk insert thousands of rows
INSERT INTO tempUpdate VALUES
    ('some new', NULL),
    ('other', 'comment'),
...

-- Start transaction for the update
BEGIN;
SET @newVersion = 5; -- Worked out out-of-band

-- Do the "deletions". The join selects all non-deleted rows in MyTable for
-- which the matching row in tempUpdate does not exist (tempUpdate.data is NULL)
UPDATE MyTable
    LEFT JOIN tempUpdate
    ON MyTable.data = tempUpdate.data AND
       MyTable.comment <=> tempUpdate.comment
    SET MyTable.deleted = @newVersion
    WHERE tempUpdate.data IS NULL AND
          MyTable.deleted IS NULL;

-- Delete all rows from the tempUpdate table that match rows in the current
-- version (deleted is null) to leave just new rows.
DELETE tempUpdate.*
    FROM MyTable RIGHT JOIN tempUpdate
    ON MyTable.data = tempUpdate.data AND
       MyTable.comment <=> tempUpdate.comment
    WHERE MyTable.id IS NOT NULL AND
          MyTable.deleted IS NULL;

-- All rows left in tempUpdate are new so add them.    
INSERT INTO MyTable (data, comment, created)
    SELECT DISTINCT tempUpdate.data, tempUpdate.comment, @newVersion
    FROM tempUpdate;

COMMIT;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tempUpdate;
```

### The question (at last)

I need to find the fastest way to do this update operation. I can't change the schema for `MyTable`, so any solution must work with that constraint. **Can you think of a faster way to do the update operation, or suggest speed-ups to my existing method?**

I have a Python script for testing the timings of different update strategies and checking their correctness over several versions. It's fairly long but I can edit into the question if people think it would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of speed-ups is for loading -- [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html).

Comment: Hmm that's new to me I'll take a look and give it a go thanks

Comment: @Day, it's only could help you to speead up loading -- not update.

Comment: After testing, writing my data to a temp file and calling `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` method (`LOCAL` as my application is on a separate box to the database) rather than doing a bulk INSERT statement has speeded up this part of the update process by a factor of 6-7. Not bad! +1

Answer (score 1):

In so far as I've experienced audit-logging, you'll be better off with two tables, e.g.:

```
yourtable (id, col1, col2, version) -- pkey on id
yourtable_logs (id, col1, col2, version) -- pkey on (id, version)
```

Then add an update trigger on yourtable, which inserts the previous version in yourtable_logs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I can't (at this point) change my schema. Will obviously have to at some point down the line when things get really massive. Also, my scenario isn't really audit-logging - the old versions can be queried regularly via an API which exposes historic versions as well as the current version, so pushing all old versions into a separate table doesn't really help with that.

Comment: I suspect it'll help more than you expect. For most queries I take it you're only interested in the latest version. In so far as I'm aware, MySQL won't use an index on a `where col is null` condition. And if so, it means your queries are constantly manipulating rows that it shouldn't.

Comment: (followed) With a logs table, you'll be able to optimally fetch live rows, at the cost of slightly degraded performance to fetch older versions of the rows. You'll also be able to more easily partition the history tables.

Comment: I see your point regarding the `where col is null` and things speeding up when we have a logs table that can't have NULL. Something to bear in mind for the future version where we have time to do it properly rather than just speeding up the update with existing schema. Thanks